# Is there a reason to simplify this and how? (JavaScript enter key function on search field)

Tags: javascript

I've got a simple function that waits for the page to load and then listens for a keyup on a input search field. This works without fail, but I think that creating functions in the global scope save on processing and help write less redundant code.

```
//Enter button functionality while search field is focused
window.onload = function() {
    var termsField = document.getElementById('search-terms');
    var searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');
    termsField.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.keyCode === 13){
            searchButton.click();
        }
    })
}
```

I tried:

```
//Enter button functionality while search field is focused
function checkKeyCode(event, buttonVariable){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13){
        buttonVariable.click();
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    var termsField = document.getElementById('search-terms');
    var searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');
    termsField.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyCode(event, searchButton));
}
```

However, this didn't seem to work as I don't think the `addEventListener` allows for passing arguments into functions.

My question: Should I try and simplify this, and if so, what are some ideas for implementing a 'cleaner' or 'better' solution? I would appreciate it if you could leave most of the code to me and just help with an working idea, so that I can get the experience. Thanks!

Comment: What you have is fine, there's no difference in using an anonymous or named function in your case, other than at best readability.

Comment: You need a closure

Comment: @adeneo - readability is more important then functionality. if you can't read the code, does it matter if it works? can you fix it if it doesn't?

Comment: @adeneo take a look at the invocation of `checkKeyCode`, it's not fine

Comment: If you want a simple code, you can use jQuery also... there's an alternative.
$("#input").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
 });
but your code is also good, it's worked

Comment: @Bergi - I meant the original working code was fine, the new version the OP tried is not fine at all. A bit clumsy of me perhaps saying "what you have is fine" !

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen With the query `event.keyCode === 13` you are checking if the typed in `keyCode` is unicode [13 - Carriage Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return). Is that what you wanted with that query? 
Or do you want to check if the typed in number is 13?

Comment: @goulashsoup I guess I'm not 100% certain. if I use `==`, will it accept 13 from the value of the 'enter' key?

Comment: @adeneo I realize both work, but I think that with my original code, I (myself) can read it easier as that's how I learned. However, is there an industry preferred method?

Comment: No, because `keyCode` returns the Unicode! The `event` has something like a `text` attribute. I will respond later!

Comment: @goulashsoup I believe keyCode is what we want as charCode only returns if the keypress was combined with the 'shift' key, correct? I could implement e.which with JQuery, but so far, the application that this is for is so simple, I'm not sure they're looking for JQuery, as I'm just working on bugs.

Comment: Why don't you try `termsField.addEventListener("keyup", function() { checkKeyCode(event, searchButton) });`

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen Ok now I am confused. What do you want to check with `event.keyCode === 13` ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using only once `termsField` and `searchButton` variables, it's not necessary to store them.

You can "*simplify*" like this

```
// Enter button functionality while search field is focused
function checkKeyCode(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13){
        document.getElementById('search-button').click();
    }
    // or, in one line
    // if (event.keyCode === 13) document.getElementById('search-button').click();
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('search-terms').addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyCode);
}
```

Comment: Now what about `buttonVariable`?

Comment: should change `checkKeyCode(event, buttonVariable)` to `checkKeyCode(buttonVariable, event)` then in addEventLister do `checkKeyCode.bind(null, buttonVariable)`

Comment: Thanks Rob! That works! Gabs00, the extra input helps!

Comment: Oops ! Bad copy and paste... Thanks @Bergi